# Ender 5 Slant or Leaning when printing multiple parts

Tags: pla, creality-ender-5

Getting slanted or leaning prints when printing multiple parts.
I checked the eccentric nuts and belts aren't rubbing anything. All works well when printing a single part. But multiple parts:

[image: Two parts that should be straight]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

*If you want a more detailed answer, you need to give more details, e.g.; "What filament are you using?" "How old is the printer?" "What mods have you made to it?"*

---

I can tell you two possibilities. Either your x or y axis is slipping which could be because of worn out belts, belts that need to be tightened, or because of too much jerk. The other is overheating of the stepper drivers so make sure the board is getting enough air over it.

Answer (score 1):

It could also be backlash in the system. Your belts aren't tight enough. Apparently the Y belt is not tight enough. That's a pretty awesome effect though.